# Pourquoi ne dit-on pas "Qu'est ce qu'un homme est"?

Tags: grammaire

La phrase "Qu'est ce qu'un homme?" semble avoir la même structure que "Qu'est ce que c'est?". Or dans la seconde phrase on répète le verbe "être", puisque le sujet du premier "est" est le mot "ce" - la phrase s'analyse de cette façon:

> Qu'est ce que c'est?
>
> (Que est ce) que (ca est)
>
> En anglais: (What is it) that (it is)

"Qu'est ce qu'un homme" semble donc ne pas être grammaticalement correcte, le mot "homme" semble être un sujet manquant un verbe, et la phrase toute entière semble correspondre à l'anglais (non-grammaticale) "What is it that a man?".

Est-ce que cette phrase est grammaticale? Pourquoi?

Comment: Please edit your question as you're mixing "qu'on homme" and "qu'un homme", and the first one (also used in the title) makes absolutely no sense...

Answer (score 1):

Ce n’est pas dans la forme grammaticale qu’il faut chercher la réponse, mais dans la substance des mots :

Le mot *homme* correspond à *un être [vivant]* par définition ; votre structure de phrase fait référence à un objet avec le mot *ça* (que j’ai remplacé par un *cela* plus conventionnel) :

> (Que est ce) que (*cela* est),

… se transforme en tautologie lorsque l’objet est remplacé par une référence à un être :

> (Que est ce) que (*un être* est).

---

***P.S.*** suite au commentaire de [Laurent S.](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/2146/laurent-s)

Un homme est une manifestation temporaire de la vie, elle-même indicible et sans cesse en recommencement, on ne peut la décrire, ni dans son unité, ni dans sa totalité.

Le troisième infini, l’infiniment complexe, peut en donner une idée.

La seule façon de la saisir est de l’écouter, d’observer en silence ce que transmettent *tous* ses propres sens y compris les plus subtiles.

Aucun mot ne peut dire le goût de la pomme à quelqu’un qui n’y a jamais goûté. Si vous prenez une photo pour dire un homme c’est *cela* (référence au verbe *avoir*), d’abord vous le réifier, ensuite vous montrez une image morte, ne serait-ce que parce qu’au moment où vous montrez la photo, l’être original n’est plus tout à fait le même, ni dans la même situation émotionnelle.

Comme les couleurs de l’arc-en-ciel, celles des verbes *être* et *avoir* ne se mélangent pas, elles ne sont pas du même registre, elles  différencient l’unité — le silence des mots — de la dualité, le monde des objets nommés par des mots que la grammaire organise.

Comment: Je butte sur la même chose que l'OP et n'arrive pas à formuler un bonne réponse: "Qu'est-ce qu'un homme ?" pur coller à votre exemple devrait être "Qu'est-ce qu'un homme est ?"  Selon moi on devrait donc se tourner vers la formule de base "Qu'est-ce que cela ?" et remplacer "cela" par "un homme", mais je n'arrive pas à retrouver une référence à cette forme interrogative que je sais pourtant correcte.

Comment: @LaurentS. — J’ai complété ma réponse.

Answer (score 1):

Dans la phrase :

> **Qu'est-ce que** c'est ?

il est vain de vouloir décomposer *qu'est ce que* en éléments indépendants.

*Qu'est-ce que* est en effet ici un pronom unique, inséparable, qui signifie simplement ***quoi***; d'ailleurs cette phrase est le plus souvent exprimée aujourd'hui en français parlé par la forme équivalente :

> C'est **quoi** ?

Dans sa forme littéraire, *quoi* est remplacé par *que* :

> ***Qu***'est-ce ? ou ***Qu***'est cela ?

*Que* et *quoi* ont alors des sens équivalents (comparer *Je ne sais pas **quoi** dire* et *je ne sais **que** dire*).

En revanche, dans la phrase :

> *Qu'est-ce qu'un homme ?*

il ne s'agit plus vraiment du pronom unique ***qu'est-ce que*** (on ne peut pas dire *Quoi un homme ?*) mais d'une expression que l'on peut cette fois décomposer en une première forme verbale interrogative ***qu'est-ce*** suivi du connecteur *que* qui sert à introduire l'objet de la question: *un homme*. On peut d'ailleurs remplacer ce deuxième *que* par une virgule :

> **Qu'est-ce**, un homme ?

*Qu'est-ce* est ici équivalent à *qu'est-ce que c'est*; ce que confirment les formes habituelles du registre courant et relâché qui sont respectivement :

> **Qu'est-ce que c'est**, un homme ?

et

> **C'est quoi**, un homme ?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer based on the assumption this is a typo and you actually want to know whether "Qu'est-ce qu'un homme ?" is grammatically correct. I indeed expect typos in both your title and question. Short answer: yes it is perfectly correct.

Longer answer:

"Qu'est-ce que c'est" is a longer, less formal and much more used nowadays, way of saying

> Qu'est-ce ?

where "ce" is the subject.

This short question can be used with a complement introduced with "que":

> Qu'est-ce que cela ?
>
> Qu'est-ce que cette chose ?
>
> Qu'est-ce qu'un homme ? (= "qu'est-ce que un homme ?", with the mandatory elision)

All could be turned around with the same meaning:

> Cela, qu'est-ce [que c'est]? (definitely not idiomatic)
>
> Cette chose, qu'est-ce [que c'est]?
>
> Un homme, qu'est-ce [que c'est]?

Your confusion probably comes from the fact you try to map every word from on translation to another, and this will fail most of the time. Indeed there's no English transposition of "Qu'est-ce que c'est". English is "What is it?" in any case (or what is that, what is this, ...), you never say "What is it it is?".

Comment: But "Qu'est ce que c'est" absolutely has an English transposition - "What is it that it is" is a word-for-word gloss andi s perfectly grammatical. The point is that with what you call the mandatory elision of the verb être, the sentence no longer seems grammatical (even in French). The question is: can we account for this sentence's structure using more general rules of French grammar, or is it just a cse of a not-strictly-correct sentence which is accepted out of habit?

Comment: I realize my answer is not that good because of the bad grammatical justification... I'll try another one and will delete this one right after